# Python Get windowtitle from Process ID or Process Name

Tags: python, windows, winapi, window

I want to get the Windowtitle of a specific process (e.g. Spotify.exe).

```
def winEnumHandler( hwnd, ctx ):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ):
        print (hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ))
```

I tried multiple different versions I found on the internet, but most solutions where for the active window, but in my case it is nit always the active window, so I have to go by process name or process id.

So, basically I'm searching for something like this

```
title = getTitleFromProcessName('Spotify.exe')
```

and then title is the corresponding window title of the spotify window.

Comment: Processes don't have names. If you want to enumerate the windows owned by a process given a particular process ID, how are you going to determine the process ID? Regardless, if you want to filter on process ID, you can call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) in your enumeration callback.

Comment: You can get the list of all top-level windows with `GetAncestor` and check PID of those windows with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`. It's not very reliable, but it works. I think I already answered same question, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: @vii You cannot enumerate all top-level windows with [`GetAncestor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getancestor). You enumerate all top-level windows using [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) which the OP is already using.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes, my mistake. Enumerate with `EnumWindows` and check if the window is top level with `GetAncestor`.

Comment: @vii `EnumWindows` enumerates top-level windows only. You do not have to check whether it is a top-level window.

Comment: What about another approach? Parse output from `TASKLIST.EXE /V /FO CSV /FI "IMAGENAME eq Spotify.exe"` (using e.g. `subprocess.Popen`)?

Comment: @JosefZ would be a good possiblity, but I found a way around using WinAPI
If anyone want to have a look at, I made a repo https://github.com/Lockna/qobuz-rpc

Comment: Feel free to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import win32gui
import win32process
import psutil
import ctypes

EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible

def getProcessIDByName():
    qobuz_pids = []
    process_name = "Qobuz.exe"

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if process_name in proc.name():
            qobuz_pids.append(proc.pid)

    return qobuz_pids

def get_hwnds_for_pid(pid):
    def callback(hwnd, hwnds):
        #if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd):
        _, found_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)

        if found_pid == pid:
            hwnds.append(hwnd)
        return True
    hwnds = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, hwnds)
    return hwnds 

def getWindowTitleByHandle(hwnd):
    length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
    buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
    return buff.value

def getQobuzHandle():
    pids = getProcessIDByName()

    for i in pids:
        hwnds = get_hwnds_for_pid(i)
        for hwnd in hwnds:
            if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                return hwnd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qobuz_handle = getQobuzHandle()
```

I solved it using this piece of code
With this I get the window handle of the qobuz window if it's open, else it's none

Comment: If you wonder where to find wingui and win32process: You must "pip install pywin32" and then "import win32.win32gui as win32gui" and "import win32.win32process as win32process".

Comment: This does not work for me. It returns empty string.